# Get data from two beans to jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I have a simply registration.

here is part of my jsp register page:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="RightsGroupRegister">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Name of group" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name of group:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name of group">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Rights" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Rights:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" id="rights" name="rights" placeholder="Rights">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And here a controller:

```
@Controller
public class RightsGroupController {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RightsGroupController.class);

private final RightsGroupService rightsGroupService;

@Inject
public RightsGroupController(RightsGroupService rightsGroupService) {
    this.rightsGroupService = rightsGroupService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "RightsGroupRegister", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getRightsGroupView() {

    LOGGER.debug("Received request for addRight");
    return new ModelAndView("RightsGroupRegister", "form", new RightsGroupForm());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "RightsGroupRegister", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createRightsGroup(@ModelAttribute("form") RightsGroupForm form ) {
    LOGGER.debug("Received request to create {}, with result={}", form);

    try {
        rightsGroupService.save(new Rightsgroup(form.getName(),form.getRights()));
    } catch (RightsGroupAlreadyExistsException e) {
        LOGGER.debug("Tried to create rightsgroup with existing id", e);
        return "right_create";
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}}
```

Now problem, I really dont understand how to work with it.
How to get to this form data from another object? for example list of Rights(id,name)?

Comment: What do you mean? you want to access the fields in `RightsGroupForm`? it looks like you are doing it already.

Comment: I want fill table or combobox with data from object Right

Comment: did you solve it? did my anser help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. I suppose you mean to access the data on the page that you are redirecting to in your post method. this is one way:

`public String createRightsGroup(@ModelAttribute("form") RightsGroupForm form, Model model)`

Add Model to your arguments in the post method. Then, i.e.:

```
model.addAttribute("name", form.getName());
model.addAttribute("rights", form.getRights());
```

and..

```
return "redirect:/right_create";
```

In your JSP (right_create.jsp) you access fields like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>${name}</td>
    <td>${rights}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

if you have a collection if `Right` you can do:

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${rights}" var="right">
   <tr>
      <td>${right.id}</td>
      <td>${right.name}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```